# Does Phaser Arcade.Body velocity include deltaTime or not?

Tags: phaser

I want to move my character along the x axis with constantly speed. I thought move depends on frame rate. So, technically I should write

```
sprite.body.velocity.x = speed * deltaTime
```

where `deltaTime = game.time.elapsedMS / 1000;`

But if I'm doing that - my character moves vvvvverrry slooow, even if `speed = 1000`.

But if I'm writing

```
sprite.body.velocity.x = speed
```

it works fine. My fps = 60;

---

[Phaser Documentation](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.8/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#velocity)
says:

> **velocity** - The velocity, or rate of change in speed of
>   the Body. Measured in pixels per second.

no deltatime....

and all demos do not have deltatime

http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/platformer-basics

http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/asteroids-movement

etc.

So, I don't understand: shoud I calculate deltaTime or just use `velocity.x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.... I think I'm stupid...

My calculation of the `deltaTime` was wrong

The correct formula will be

```
deltaTime = (elapsedMS * fps) / 1000
```

[elapsedMS](http://phaser.io/docs/2.5.0/Phaser.Time.html#elapsedMS) - The time in ms since the last time update, in milliseconds, based on time.

[fps](http://phaser.io/docs/2.5.0/Phaser.Time.html#fps) - Frames per second.
(Only calculated if [advancedTiming](http://phaser.io/docs/2.5.0/Phaser.Time.html#advancedTiming) is enabled).

So, that was my problem.

---

As the result

[body.velocity](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.8/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#velocity) doesn't include calculation of deltaTime and for smooth movement should use deltaTime that calculated by the formula above.

And it will be something like that

```
function update() { // <-- it is phaser state method...is called every frame
    deltaTime = (elapsedMS * fps) / 1000;
    sprite.body.velocity.x = velocityX * deltaTime;
    sprite.body.velocity.y = velocityY * deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I had the same exact issue with the deltaTime. Now, how to add speed? Would we just need to add ` * playerSpeed`?

Comment: @NiCkNewman In my example `velocityX` and `velocityY`  is my *player speed* on axis x/y ..... so, you can write `playerSpeed * deltaTime`  instead velocityX/velocityY.....))  also it is located inside the `update` method.........And also ( just in case ) -- [body.velocity](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#velocity) measured in pixels per second.....So, if I understood the documentation right, you don't need even the "**+**" (plus) sign in the formula ...just `sprite.body.velocity.x = speed * deltaTime;` instead of  `sprite.body.velocity.x += velocityX * deltaTime;`..

Comment: i know i'm a bit late here, but why are you multiplying velocity by time to get velocity?  that doesn't make any sense; either add velocity to velocity, or multiply _acceleration_ by time to get velocity.

Comment: @Eevee read a comment above) I can edit the post if this is confusing you

Comment: but speed is just the magnitude of velocity.  multiply speed by time gives you a _distance_, which you can't add to velocity.  that's why your player was moving very slowly.  in the code in this answer, `elapsed * fps / 1000` is going to be about 1 — _not_ delta time — because the time between frames is naturally about `1/fps`

Comment: It looks like in Phaser velocity is calculated as pixels per frame, not per second, for some reason.